# How to add a special unit to a string vector depending on the string in R

Tags: r, string, vector

My vector can contain at most the following strings. The names always stay the same. The only difference is that the vector does not always have to contain all strings and the order can be mixed up.

```
v.names <- c("spotDE", "spotFR", "windDE", "resLoadDE", "nuclearFR", "solarDE", 
             "consumptionDE", "capNucDE", "temperatureDE", "temperatureFR",
             "capLigDE", "capHardCDE", "capGDE", "capDerivedGDE", "capODE", 
             "capHydroPumpDE", "capHydroResDE", "capRoRDE", "capNucFR", "capHardCFR", 
             "capGFR", "capOFR", "capBiomassFR", "capHydroPumpFR", "capHydroResFR", "capRoRFR")
```

Now, depending on which string is in the vector, I would add an additional string with the units. What I want to have is the following:

```
v.names <- c("spotDE \u20ac/MWh", "spotFR \u20ac/MWh", "windDE MWh/h", "resLoadDE MWh/h", 
             "nuclearFR MWh/h", "solarDE MWh/h", "consumptionDE MWh/h", 
             "temperatureDE °C", "temperatureFR °C", 
             "capNucDE MW", "capLigDE MW", "capHardCDE MW", "capGDE MW", "capDerivedGDE MW", 
             "capODE MW", "capHydroPumpDE MW", "capHydroResDE MW", "capRoRDE MW", "capNucFR MW", 
             "capHardCFR MW", "capGFR MW", "capOFR MW", "capBiomassFR MW", "capHydroPumpFR MW", 
             "capHydroResFR MW", "capRoRFR MW")
```

Every string that begins with `spot..` should have the following string added: `" \u20ac/MWh"`. Every string that begins with `temperature..` should have the following string added: `" °C`. Every string that begins with `cap.....` should have the following string added: `" MW"`. The remaining strings should have `" MWh/h"` added.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `case_when` to assign prefixes based on condition.

```
library(dplyr)
result <- paste0(v.names, case_when(grepl('^spot', v.names) ~ " \u20acMWh", 
                                    grepl('^temperature', v.names) ~ " °C", 
                                    grepl('^cap', v.names) ~ " MW", 
                                    TRUE ~ " MWh/h"))
```